# How to get the item tapped in a list view and send it to another Page

Tags: xamarin.forms

hi i'm new to xamarin forms and i did some quit  googling didn't find much 
i have a class Account that a list in a ListView and i would like the get the item tapped and show more details about that item in another page if somebody can help

Comment: I think some code will help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this is a good starting point [Interactivity](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/interactivity/)

ListView supports selection of one item at a time. Selection is on by default. When a user taps an item, two events are fired: ItemTapped and ItemSelected. Note that tapping the same item twice will not fire multiple ItemSelected events, but will fire multiple ItemTapped events. Also note that ItemSelected will be called if an item is deselected.

Be aware that ItemSelected is called both when items are deselected and when they are selected. That means you'll need to check for null SelectedItem in your ItemSelected event handler before you can use it:

```
void OnSelection (object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.SelectedItem == null) {
    return; //ItemSelected is called on deselection, which results in SelectedItem being set to null
  }
  DisplayAlert ("Item Selected", e.SelectedItem.ToString (), "Ok");
  //((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null; //uncomment line if you want to disable the visual selection state.
}
```

if you want to Push a page, you can

```
Navigation.PushAsync(new MyPage(e.SelectedItem));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  **Use ItemSelected event for list item tapped,like this**        

    <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding TopicList}" HasUnevenRows="True" ItemSelected="PlayVideo">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
               <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.View>
                         //implement code here
                    </ViewCell.View>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
       </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>

  On .cs file:
  public void PlayVideo(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
   {
       TestList testView = new TestList();            
       Navigation.PushAsync(testView);
   }
```